# Выбор выпадающего меню js, jquery и обработка выбора пункта меню?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, python

Посоветуйте готовое многоуровневое горизонтальное выпадающее меню.
И подскажите как обработать выбор пункта меню?
Т.е. у меня есть скажем меню:

```
продукты | Алкоголь |
  |....         |___Коньяк 
  |....         |___Пиво
  |....               |__светлое
                      |__темное
```

как узнать, что скажем пользователь выбрал темное пиво и уже в скрипте (python cgi) на основе этого выбора делать выборку из базы?

насчет как получить значение, придумал такое.

```
print "<a href=\"?a_graid=test\">aaa</a>"

form = cgi.FieldStorage()
t = form.getfirst('a_graid', '')
print t
```

Comment: А меню то на чём реализовано ? если на что-то типа HTML/Select то можно сделать onChange() и дальше просто выбрать по document.getElementById("element_id").selectedIndex

Comment: @vnn198, меню нашел на jquery+css, называется smartmenus вот только проблемы с ним у меня. Вернее с его отображением. у меня оно должно отображаться в фрейме. Если я его вызываю вне фрейма, то вид нормальный горизонтальный, а если внутри страницы (внутри фрейма скрипт страницы грузить) то идет столбиком...

Comment: ну тогда надо смотреть на документацию этого smartmenus  http://www.smartmenus.org/docs/ , как я понимаю тебе нужно Events/click

Answer (score 1):

Вот кусок из документации на smartmenus

**click -**
*Fired when an item is clicked. You can cancel the event with return false and the item will not be selected (i.e. it's link won't be loaded) and if there is a sub menu which should appear on click, it won't be shown, too. This event is fired even for disabled items so you may want to check the select event, too.
Cancelable: Yes
Arguments:
e
The jQuery.Event object.
item
The menu item  element.
Code sample:*

```
$('#main-menu').bind('click.smapi', function(e, item) {});
```

Comment: мне сейчас нужно, чтобы меню нормально смотрелось, до кликов еще не дошел. я же писал выше, что в фрейме оно у меня вертикальное. выравниваю каждый тег li, но смотрится ужасно. так что буду искать другое

Comment: форматирование меню скорее всего через CSS идёт, можно в том-же хроме->Developer tools (F12) посмотреть что конкретно уезжает и поправить, а клик нужен для загрузки твоего python cgi, надо его вызвать внутри function(e, item) {}

Comment: http://www.la2oldschool.ru//cgi-bin/tradearea/all_lot.cgi
вот так оно выглядит, если не в фрейме. в фрейме пункты один под одним вертикально получаются

Comment: в sm-blue.css есть параметр min-width: 768px, видимо у тебя фрейм меньше этого значения, поставь 1px или лучше подбери значение в которое гарантированно влазит твоё меню

Comment: ну да. у меня 700px. я пробовал в main-menu прописывать. А это получается надо именно в  sm-blue.css изменить 768 на свое?

Comment: либо там прописать , либо оверрайднуть своим значением

Comment: не. прокатило. а что значит оверрайднуть?

Comment: это перезаписать значение определив его позже, чтобы новое заменило старое, таким образом та CSS останется не тронутой, а новый стиль просто перезапишет значение min-width: на новое

Answer (score 0):

саму таблицу в с помощю CSS и можно добавить через jquery свойство toggle(); которое позволяет выпадать меню сверху в низ(в данном случае).И добавить событие onclick();.вообщем почитай об этом...Там очень просто буквально строк 5 кода в JS.